# UIImageView can't change position programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm currently developing iPhone apps where i need to reposition the UIImageView. This is so far what i did so far:

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
import AVFoundation
import QuartzCore

class _DBubbleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var BubbleBackground: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Bubble: UIImageView!


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
Bubble.frame = CGRect(x: 168, y: 220, width: Bubble.bounds.size.width,      height: Bubble.bounds.size.height)
```

I have checked `@IBAction` is properly connected, but when I run the program, the `UIImageView` position does not changed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: do you use storyboard? the project is autolayout?

Comment: If you are using auto layout, you need to use constraints to position the UIImage. Or you can set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` for the view the UIImage is contained in. Otherwise, constraints are generated when you add the UIImageView for you which ends up forcing the image back to that point whenever layout happens, which is what you are seeing. I would suggest you use constraints of the UIImageView.

Comment: @tagy22 Yup i'm using storyboard and using auto layout too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Storyboard, click on your UIImageView and add a constraint for the leading edge and a constraint for the top edge.

CTRL Drag from each constraint in the view hierarchy into your swift file and add IBOutlets for each constraint: Call them `bubbleLeadingConstraint` and `bubbleTopConstraint`.

Change you code to:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear()

  bubbleLeftConstraint.constant = 168;
  bubbleTopConstraint.constant = 220;
}
```

If you want to change the width/height, add constraints for that too and set in the code.

You can now change the position by changing the constraints. You can also animate any change by changing the constants and placing `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in an animation block.

Comment: Nice! i got it working with this method! Million thanks! @Rory McKinnel